# Postgresql : Sorting JSON array by numeric key value

Tags: arrays, json, postgresql, sql-order-by, aggregate-functions

I've been reading similar questions which look to have simple enough solutions, but applying them here doesn't seem to be working for me. 
I have a json column in a postgres database table which contains x and y co-ordinates. Performing a simple select on this column gives back the following for example :

```
[
{
 "x": "-1.6827080672804147",
 "y": "-0.011726425465745486"
},
{
 "x": "2.4016256261667235",
 "y": "0.016304356672382222"
},
{
 "x": "0.2278035109735127",
 "y": "0.0013854154958112177"
},
{
 "x": "1.2104642489702613",
 "y": "0.008129416140682903"
},
{
 "x": "-0.3281865438803838",
 "y": "-0.0024303442506510738"
},
{
 "x": "-0.2401461868455415",
 "y": "-0.0018261232803209514"
}, 
               .
               .
               .
               .
]
```

I would like to return this object ordered in terms of the x coordinate ascending. The above resultset was actually the result of running the following query:

```
  SELECT coordinates 
    FROM schema_name.table_name
   WHERE ....
     AND ....
ORDER BY coordinates ->> 'x' asc;
```

I also tried using

```
ORDER BY cast(coordinates->>'x' as numeric)  ASC
```

which yields the following:

```
ERROR:  cannot cast type json to numeric
```

I'm sure it's something silly I'm missing. Any pointers in the right direction would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: `ORDER BY (coordinates->>'x')::NUMERIC`

Comment: Thanks for the prompt reply @eurotrash. Unfortunately, although it doesn't throw an error, the ordering of the returning json is the exact same as what I posted initially.

Comment: Is that JSON array from one field or is each x/y from a separate record?

Comment: It's just coming from the one field.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You should use `order by` in `json_agg()`. You may want to define a function that can be useful in various contexts:

```sql
create or replace function sort_my_array(json)
returns json language sql immutable as $$
    select json_agg(value order by (value->>'x')::numeric)
    from json_array_elements($1)
$$;

select sort_my_array(coordinates)
from my_table
```

If you do not like custom functions, use `json_array_elements()` in a lateral join:

```sql
select json_agg(value order by (value->>'x')::numeric)
from my_table
cross join json_array_elements(coordinates)
```

Test it in [db<>fiddle.](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_10&fiddle=9663ee9aa494bd6768e0067852cd89c6)

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion @klin. This works and probably is the more elegant solution alright.

Answer (score 1):

Since all those elements are in one field, by ordering it you're transforming the data, so you'll need to take it apart, order it, then put it back together.

```
SELECT ('[' || STRING_AGG(j::TEXT, ',' ORDER BY (j->>'x')::NUMERIC) || ']')::JSON
FROM json_array_elements(
'[
{"x": "2.4016256261667235","y": "0.016304356672382222"},
{"x": "-1.6827080672804147","y": "-0.011726425465745486"},
{"x": "0.2278035109735127","y": "0.0013854154958112177"}
]'::JSON) j
```

Result:

> [{"x": "-1.6827080672804147","y": "-0.011726425465745486"},{"x": "0.2278035109735127","y": "0.0013854154958112177"},{"x": "2.4016256261667235","y": "0.016304356672382222"}]

I should note that I *think* in later versions of PG there may be better ways to construct a JSON object than STRING_AGG'ing, but I use PG 9.3, so...

Comment: Very good. I just constructed a proc which includes your suggestion and calling it works a charm. Accepting your answer. Thanks again for the assistance.